# How to pass data from one component to another while using API in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, we can pass data from one component to another using `props` but I want to know how to pass data from one component to another while issueing an API request.

In the backend, the signin credentials [are authenticated using "JWT authentication"](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-2-creating-and-validating-jwt-json-web-token/).

How to pass the the username while the user is getting logged in?
When the user get's logged in, my page should show "welcome ".

You can check out the code in [this CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-elgamal-u3xee)

Here is the json data from the API:

```
{
  item: [
    {
      "id": "145741863",
      "firstName": "ABCDEF",
      "email": "qwerty@yahoo.com",
      "password": "Aertyuio",
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using react-router push method. It also has the ability to send different props value along with your pathname and this push will work only on components wrapped in .

In your case, you need to pass a state along with your route name. Below changes, you have to pass state along with your route name in `history.push`.

`this.props.history.push("/Welcome", { ...res });` on `Login.js`.

And get the response values on your `Welcome.js` by using `this.props.location.state.firstName`.

Attaching the document for your reference - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md

And Also, I attached a basic demonstration of history.push in this - https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-flower-hbglx.

Comment: I'm getting the value undefined. Could you assist me where i'm going wrong. I have updated json data in the query.

Comment: could you check whether your response is coming through the `this.props.location.state`.If it is undefined means then check on your `history.push`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
axios
      .post(`/api/Login/auth`, data, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.props.history.push("/Welcome", { ...res });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data.message);
        var res = err.response.data.message;
        this.setState({ errorMsg: res });
      });
```

And as you are sending `JSON Web Token` as data, you can access it as:

```
this.props.data.item[0].firstName
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: HI i'm getting the value as undefined. Could you assist me where i'm going wrong. I have updated json data in the query

Comment: Look for the response you are receiving via axios. And access the property accordingly. I have also updated my answer. Try that also.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use some state management library such as [redux](https://redux.js.org).

Otherwise you will need to have a component that will do this fetching stuff and this component should be a common ancestor to the components that will be at least affected with the data changes from API.

> My objective is how to pass the the user name while user is getting logged in. When User gets logged in then it should show "welcome Username".

As a more generic solution, you can create a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that will do the fetching API stuff and return a new component with the data from the API injected as props.